# Can the new Galaxy Note 10.1 make and receive phone calls?

Tags: calls, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I know that Galaxy Note 10.1 has multiple editions (one of them is LTE chip).

Can it make and receive ordinary phone calls? Like using ordinary signals, instead of the Internet ones.

I couldn't find any information on this.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only skype or other voip options. It does not have a GSM module on it, it just has a small chip for data transfers.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! As this phone doesnot have any support for GSM, or what you can say the SIM cards that would provide you a functionality to send and recieve messages or phone calls on the go, this phone doesnot allow you to make or recieve phone calls.

However, you can use VOIP, such as Google Voice, or Skype by Microsoft. To make phone calls, however if you want to make a phone call such as one you would make by any GSM supporting phone, it won't be happening here! You need to get 24x7 WiFi connection, to make sure you are alive. Otherwise just download Angry birds and play it in the meantime.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This phablet most certainly can make and receive calls, this depends  on which model you own The p601 and p605 work on GSM, LTE. If you own the P600 you need WiFi for calls or a blue toothed  head set.

Please do your research. .
http://m.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_10_1_(2014_edition)-5677.php

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Use a Bluetooth headset and the phone app.